# Serilog Not Working on .Net Framework 4.7

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serilog, .net-4.8

So I'm trying to implement logging into my .Net framework Web API project but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

I read on their Github page that I need to use Serilog.AspNetCore version `3.4.0` with .Net framework, so I already did that. Now as far as I am aware I don't need to downgrade anything else, since it isn't mentioned in the Github, so the following are the version of dependencies:

```
Serilog 2.12.0
Serilog.AspNetCore 3.4.0
Serilog.Extentions.Logging 3.0.1
Serilog.Sinks.Debug 1.0.1
Serilog.Sinks.File 5.0.0
```

Here is my code for logging:

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/GetOnboardCaseDetail")]
        [ActionName("LoadNew")]
        public async Task<RF_CASE> GetOnboardCaseDetail(int caseID,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File("./logs/myapp.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

            Log.Logger.Debug("test");
            Log.Logger.Error("Testt");
            Log.Logger.Information("test");
            Log.CloseAndFlush();

        }
```

I'm new to ASP .NET but if I understand correctly, when I trigger the API, it should create the `myapp.txt` file in `bin/logs`. But when I search the whole project, I cannot find the file text file anywhere. I don't know if I'm supposed to do any other changes or not, as this is all the changes that I have made to the code. Would really appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake here.

Comment: Does the user your IIS application runs as (usually the default AppPool identity) have permissions to create a directory at `logs` inside its own working directory? Other things to watch for are using relative paths, as sometimes they aren't where you expect. You should use the appropriate APIs to canonicalise the path for where the log file should be.

Comment: Hi. I followed your advice and used the absolute path instead. Turns out that works. When I used the relative path it threw `UnauthorizedAccessException` error. In your opinion, where would be the best place for me to store the log files? I don't want to place it in the project folder.

Comment: I would either write them within `App_Data`, or configure a dedicated directory on the machine and give IIS write access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **MinimumLevel.Debug()** As follows,

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.File("./logs/myapp.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue(Log.debug) not working/logging in .net framework:

Following did not work(Log.Information was working but Log.debug was not):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(@"D:\MyProject\Logs#.log").CreateLogger();
```

But Following worked-Both Log.Debug and Log.Information was working(adding **MinimumLevel.Debug()**):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Debug().WriteTo.File(@"D:\MyProject\Logs#.log").CreateLogger();
```